# Redirecting to Facebook story page or some sharing page

Tags: html, url, redirect

How can I be able to redirect to the Facebook story or any sharing page by clicking on a link?
(https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=https://quitly.in/) Like this, when you click on this, you will be redirected to LinkedIn to the post section with some text.

Comment: Open which you want to redirect to in a tab , copy its link and add like above to redirect to it

Comment: I think you did not get my point.

Comment: https://www.instagram.com/sachintendulkar/ : link to sachintendulkar insta

Comment: if you want redirect on button click then use either `<a>` tag or button for that

Comment: If not that than illustrate your question in a better way